# Naming a REST service GET with extensive parameter list

Tags: rest, web-services, architecture, software-design

Assume that you are getting some meta-data associated with students, and you are designing a REST web service to do so.  Obviously you could do a GET for each student, but you would prefer to get all students at once.  Assuming that the ids and the number of students are "too long".  That is, that we may be querying 200 students each with an id length of 32 chars, well beyond a safe URL length.

How would you overcome this?

One method is to use a PUT or a POST and pass in a data structure with the student Id's.  Which would you choose?

If choosing that method what would you name such a service?

What are some other options?

Comment: Why would you ever need to retrieve data about 200 **specific** student's at once? What actually is the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET-ting one by one is certainly not a very good solution.

I'd use POST, with the student IDs in a JSON array. 
Something like

```
[{"id":"32charstudentId1"},
 {"id":"32charstudentId2"},
 {"id":"32charstudentId3"}]
```

This is fairly easy to iterate over at the back-end and does the job, just fine.
And the response could be something like

```
[
   {
   "id":"32charstudentId1",
   "meta1":"some info",
    "meta2": "some more info"
   },
   {
   "id":"32charstudentId2",
   "meta1":"some info",
    "meta2": "some more info"
   },
   {
   "id":"32charstudentId3",
   "meta1":"some info",
    "meta2": "some more info"
   }]
```

The name of the service really depends on what utility it provides to you.
To be generic you could simply call it something like
    "FetchStudentDetails"

---

A simple array with Student IDs will work just as well, I guess.

An (sort of crude) alternative could be sending sending a POST with student IDs in a string, delimited by a delimiter of your choice, i prefer the semi-colon(;).

Comment: That is the very solution I came up with, it was part of a real world problem that I was asked in an interview question.  I did not get the offer being called "un-creative".  Sometimes creativity in software development is not a good thing, and I think this is the case.  In such naming, you self document what the service is for, which to me is very desirable.

Comment: Names should be meaningful, creativity in naming doesn't matter much to me.

Comment: Agreed!  TY for your input.